# how to split a very long row data into two column by python (from txt file)

Tags: python, split

I have a txt file which has a very long row of datat (e.g as below)

```
234.45  234.3455 667.4556 566.3311 332.333 564.322 554.2564 21.203
```

I want to read that `.txt` file with python and want to split the data into two column as below:

```
234.45  234.3455
667.4556 566.3311
332.333 564.322
554.2564 21.203
```

I am new to python and I am not sure how to load the read .txt file and split the data into column? Anyone can help me? Thanks ahead.

Comment: From your first item to second itemyou have two spaces, all the others have one space. Is this your actual file format or just a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you loop through every item and if the index of the item in the list is even you add to `col1` and otherwise add to `col2`

This will work with items separated by any number of spaces

```
import re
with open("test.txt") as f:
    inputString = f.read()

#remove all extra spaces so all items separated by only one space
inputString = re.sub(r" +", " ", inputString)

itemsInString = inputString.split(" ")

col1 = []
col2 = []
for index, item in enumerate(itemsInString):
    if index % 2 == 0:
        col1.append(float(item))
    else:
        col2.append(float(item))

print(col1)
print(col2)
```

This gives you the following:
col1 = `[234.45, 667.4556, 332.333, 554.2564]` 
col2 = `[234.3455, 566.3311, 564.322, 21.203]`

Writing it back out to a file:

```
writeString = ""
for item in zip(col1, col2):
    writeString += str(item[0]) + " " + str(item[1]) + "\n"

with open("outfile.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(writeString)
```

And here's a more optimized way to write to file without string concatenation but it's less clear

```
with open("outfile.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(([" ".join([str(a[0]), str(a[1])]) for a in zip(col1, col2)])))
```

Comment: hi @Racialz, Thanks for your advice. It works but when I print(item), it shows all data in column  . So, am doing something wrong, cos I want to print them in two columns. Tks again.

Comment: Use `print(col1)` and `print(col2)` outside the for loop

Comment: hi sorry to forget to answer. the space is not fixed. Can it effect on the code? Tks.

Comment: Yeah, i'll update my answer to allow for variable number of spaces, you will get a float conversion error if you dont

Comment: oh yeahh got it. sorry to disturb you again and my ignorance. If i want to save back those two columns into text file, how shall i command it.

Comment: I'll update my post in a sec with how to save it back

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help @Racialz. It helps me a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have a file called 'sample.txt'. You can do

```
f = open('sample.txt', 'r')
```

This will open the file, now for reading the contents of the file, you can use method **readlines** which will return you list of lines or rows whatever you call them. Now, each line is string and lets say this data is separated by whitespace you can use **split** method on line to generate columns.

So, your code could be something like this

```
f = open('sample.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    columns = line.split(' ')
    print(columns)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is wrong, he wants to split the information into columns so that every other item is together. All this does is a line by spaces, it doesn't show the process of grouping every other item

Comment: @Racialz Yes my bad, I overlooked the grouping part.

Answer (score 1):

Opens the file

```
fp = open('concernedfile.txt', 'r')
```

Read returns everything in the file as a string.

Split separates each number into list items.

Read more about split at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm

```
before_split = fp.read()
data = before_split.split()
```

Finding the length of the list and appending data

```
x = len(data)
col1 = []
col2 = []
for i in range(0,x):
    if (i % 2 == 0):
        col1.append(data[i])
    else:
        col2.append(data[i])
```

Zip can help you aggregate data structures

```
combinedcol = zip(col1, col2)
```

Printing columns as tuples. You can make changes here with ease.

```
for i in combinedcol:
        print i
```

Answer (score 0):

Read file :

```
fp = open("abc.txt")
content = fp.read();
lines = content.split("\t") #split row by tab spaces to form a list
```

Split the input row to two lists :

```
l1=[]  #list1 to store col 1
l2=[]  #list2 to store col 2
for i in range(0,len(lines)):
    if(i%2 == 0):
        l2.append(lines[i])
    else:
        l1.append(lines[i])
```

Zip the list to form groups(which you may later write to files):

```
for x in list(zip(l1,l2)):
    print(x)
```

Write to file :

```
fp=open("E:/efg.txt",'a')
for x in list(zip(l1,l2)):
    fp.write(('\t'.join(x)))
    fp.write('\n')
```